# Position computed item below element of flexbox

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, flexbox

I'm loooking for some advice concerning the following problem.

I want to position several elements inside a flexbox since the feature shall adapt to its surroundings.
Below one of these items I want to position a computed element which will use the size of the element above it. So in essence it has a fixed (but calculated) size.

I tried solving the issue by placing the calculated element into the flexbox, but this destroys the overall behavior.

It is supposed to look roughly like this:

```
<Label w/o shrink> <input element, can grow>             <Label w/o shrink>
                   <some rectangle, calculated size>
```

[desired layout - a link since I'm not allowed to post images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIfII.png)

In the attached example [jsfiddle example of problem](https://jsfiddle.net/mikeMyer4242/8wob2adu/1/) I'm using an input element in combination with two labels and a computed rectangle to describe the behavior. Think of the rectangle as a generic example for the problem.

Resizing of the window in terms of enlarging the window works like a charm.
Issues occur when decreasing the size.

Flex can only decrease the size of elements with a non-fixed size, such as the input element. My computed rectangle has a fixed size. So this size prevents any shrinkage of the input+rectangle container.

**Idea 1**: Make the calculated item a little smaller than the related input so the container itself can shrink since there is space. The input will shrink and thus the calculated rectangle will shrink as well.
See [jsfiddle with a smaller rectangle](https://jsfiddle.net/mikeMyer4242/ez9usdc6/3/)

This works to some degree. If the mouse moves slowly enough when resizing the window / the changes in size happen slowly, everything is fine.
As soon as the shrinkage happens too fast for the rendering to keep up, the issue as described above occurs again.

**Idea 2:** Ignore the calculated element by positioning it absolutely.
See here: [jsfiddle with relative and absolute positioning](https://jsfiddle.net/mikeMyer4242/403s6ck7/3/)

I defined the outer element to be positioned relatively and the inner (the calculated element w/ "constant" width) to be positioned absolutely.
By doing this the element will be taken from the flow and everything works fine.
*Almost*.
Since now the rectangle is ignored, the remaining layout gets broken as well. This is not acceptable due to the usage of this feature as a component in a bigger context. In the example the last label gets positioned too high up since the div won't take into account the rectangle.

My question now is if you have further advice. If at all possible I want to avoid any calculations in javascript and solve the issue using css-related options. (Otherwise using further info of `getBoundingClientRect()` - such as the x position - might have been an option in some way (?) -> this way I could remove the rectangle completely from the flexbox and just position it "by hand" at the desired position).

I am happy about any further ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people who might have a similar issue here's another approach I came up with while trying to adapt James solution.

See this jfiddle: [jsfiddle using overflow and min-width](https://jsfiddle.net/2ugs4qtm/)

What I changed about my first solution:
The issue with the shrinkage is some chicken-and-egg issue: The flexbox cannot shrink further than the elements inside allow for shrinkage, but then my computed element only shrinks if another element shrinks which in turn is prevented by the flexbox itself being unable to shrink, which brings us back to the beginning.

So in my question I tried to make the flexbox ignore the element by positioning it absolutely - which messes up the overall layout.

A solution I came up with in order to allow shrinkage: Make some of the elements be able to overflow the flexbox and allow for a `min-width` different to `auto`.

This way I allow the calculated element to `overflow` the flexbox (which makes the flexbox kinda ignore the item). Note that you also want to adjust the min-width of certain elements.

So in the end I introduced a second flexbox which encapsulates the computed element. Both this element as well as the items inside allow both for overflow and shrinkage. (One might be able to simplify the elements a little).

The computed element can thus breach/overflow its boundaries and the overall construct can shrink. The shrinkage causes the computed element to resize right away - so temporary overflow gets fixed immediately.

You can compare this approach to James idea and decide which one suits your troubles better.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be caused by using the width of the input `someInput` to calculate the `computed-element-container` width. If you use the flex item width instead then it should work. 
I've [updated your jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jamarmstrong/h9rz1t4b/) to show this - I've created a second flex container above the original, that has the same three items. I then calculate the width based on an element with id: `content-box`. Hopefully this will assist you with finding a solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/jamarmstrong/h9rz1t4b/

Comment: Hey James


thanks a lot for your idea.


I came up with another (and cleaner I'd say) solution. But here's what one might salvage from your approach:


One could put the "upper elements" (in this example the labels and the input) in one seperate flexbox and then put the other element (here: the rectangle) in a second flexbox right below the first one.
One only has to put in "empty" placeholders for the single "columns".

Comment: I'm relatively new to actually participating at stackoverlfow, so my question is: Which answer am I supposed to accept? This one made me think and come up with a different approach which solved the deal. So I accepted my own solution and simply upvoted this one. I hope that is the correct way of doing things around here.